# Spring Integration Flow Level CorrelationId for logging and tracking flow

Tags: spring-integration

My flow starts with a polling inbound adapter which hands off the processing to a downstream components on pub/sub channels with async executors and service activator (orchestrator using 2 gateways)

**Questions**

**1.** I would like to log a correlation id for every execution of a poll so that I can track the logs for that flow execution independently from another execution of the same flow using this correlationId, something similar to a MDC with UUID. How do I pass this to all the threads involved in the processing and output the correlationId in the log statement?

**2.** I am also trying to figure out what is the best approach for logging. Currently I have a logging wireTap (consumed by a logging adapter) on all channels. For this one, I want to be able to enable the wireTap interception only when the logging mode is DEBUG
For example,

```
 <int:logging-channel-adapter log-full-message="true"
                                 logger-name="tapInbound"
                                 level="DEBUG"
                                 id="loggingChannel"/>
```

This will only log when application logger is DEBUG, but the wireTap interception will always happen. How to enable the wireTap interception only when log level is DEBUG? Probably by using `selector-expression` with value of something like `isloggingLevelDebug()`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use an [advice on the poller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers), or a custom interceptor on the first channel, to set the correlation.
2. Instead of declaring the wire taps declaratively in XML, you could programmatically add them to the channels in a `SmartLifecycle` bean in an early phase (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

Comment: How to configure MDC for async hand off? I have various async flows and would like to have MDC in there.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it doesn't help people find questions/answers. `MDC.copyContextMap()` - add it as a message header and set the MDC from it in the new thread,

Comment: Sure, I will take care of this next time. Thank you !